# How are multiple instances of Hasura GraphQL Engine and Postgres run locally via Docker?

Tags: graphql, hasura

The `docker-compose.yaml` to spin up Hasura + Postgres locally, have commands to start a single instance of both. How can multiple instances (say, for multiple projects) be setup locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source `docker-compose.yaml` file needs to be modified to include multiple volumes of Postgresql and Hasura GraphQL Engine, in addition to allocating ports for them.
[This](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/pull/5464) is a good example of how it is done.